# PassportJS throwing an error when asked to save a 'remember_me' token to db

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

I'm attempting to set up a Passport Local strategy with the **remember me** feature. The idea, as recommended by PassportJS docs, is to detect if the *Remember me* option is checked and if so, generate a unique token and store it to a **tokens* collection in the db.

My route is currently set up like this:

```
router.post('/',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    async (req, res, next) => {
      const {body: {remember_me, username}} = req;
      // issue a remember me cookie if the option was checked
      if (!remember_me) { return next(); }

      const token = uuidv4();
      Token.save(token, { userId: req.user.id }, function(err) {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        res.cookie(process.env.USER_REMEMBER_COOKIE, token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 604800000 }); // 7 days
        return next();
      });
    },
    (req, res) => {
      res.cookie(process.env.USER_DATA_COOKIE, signedUserData(req), {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
      });
      res.json({ success: true });
    });
```

However, when I enter the username and password with the checkbox checked, instead of adding a token to the db and returning the cookie, Passport is throwing the following error on `Token.save()`:

> TypeError: _token.default.save is not a function

Where am I going wrong? The collection exists and so does the model. The latter looks like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
  token: String,
  userId: String,
});

const Token = mongoose.model('token', tokenSchema);

module.exports = Token;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mongoose syntax error. replace:

```
Token.save(token, { userId: req.user.id }, function(err) {...}
```

with:

```
(new Token({token, userId: req.user.id})).save(function(err) {...})
```

---

Detailed:

1. A mongoose model like `Token` has no method called `save`. you should create an instance of it, and then that instance has a method called `save` to save it into database.
2. you used `token, { userId: req.user.id }` wich should be `{token, userId: req.user.id }`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Now at least there's no error. But the db still wouldn't update. In fact, `save()` doesn't even trigger because a `console.log()` inside `save(function(err) {...})` doesn't get executed!

Comment: @TheLearner so perhaps your `passport.authenticate` wont pass. add a `console.log()` in line 4 and 6 and ect, and check whats happening